# Was bedeutet "nicht obsolet" hier im Satz?

Tags: grammaticality

Der Satz:

> Der europäische Emissionshandel macht eine aktive Klimaschutzpolitik
>   im Stromsektor nicht obsolet.

Ich verstehe den Satz nur bis "nicht obsolet". Ist diese Konstruktion grammatikalisch korrekt?

Comment: Tipp: Streiche *obsolet*, setze dafür *unnötig*.  --> "...handel macht nicht unnötig...". Andersrum ausgedrückt: "Trotz des Emissionshandels ist Klimaschutzpolitik weiterhin notwendig"

Comment: Ja, diese Konstruktion ist absolut grammatikalisch korrekt. Warum zweifelst du daran? Und geht es dir nicht eher um die Bedeutung des Wortes *obsolet* in dem Kontext? So oder so, mir ist nicht ganz klar, was du hier frägst.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ja, die Konstruktion ist grammatisch korrekt.

Das Schema, nach dem der Satz konstruiert ist, lautet:

> **A** macht **B** nicht **C**.

Dabei können für A und B Nomen oder Nominalphrasen eingesetzt werden; C ist ein Platzhalter für ein Adjektiv.

Nach genau demselben Muster sind die folgenden Beispiele gestrickt, in denen ich zur Veranschaulichung A, B und C in eckige Klammern setze:

> [Hans]<sub>A</sub> macht [Erika]<sub>B</sub> nicht [glücklich]<sub>C</sub>.
>   [Die Zugabe von klarem Wasser]<sub>A</sub> macht [frisch gebrühten Kaffee]<sub>B</sub> nicht [süßer]<sub>C</sub>.
>   [Der Handel mit Erdnüssen innerhalb Bayerns]<sub>A</sub> macht [Maßnahmen um das Aussterben von Elefanten zu verhindern]<sub>B</sub> nicht [überflüssig]<sub>C</sub>.

Der nachgefragte Satz sieht mit meinen Verzierungen so aus:

> [Der europäische Emissionshandel]<sub>A</sub> macht [eine aktive Klimaschutzpolitik im Stromsektor]<sub>B</sub> nicht [obsolet]<sub>C</sub>.

---

Falls die einzelnen Teile des Satzes unklar sein sollten:

**A**
**Der europäische Emissionshandel**
Das ist der Handel mit Emissionen innerhalb Europas.
Detaillierter: Europäische Staaten haben sich vertraglich verpflichtet, den Ausstoß (= die Emission) von Treibhausgasen zu begrenzen. Aber es ist erlaubt, über das vertragliche Maß hinaus Treibhausgase zu emittieren, wenn ein anderer Staat dafür auf einen Teil der ihm zugestandenen Menge verzichtet, so dass die Gesamtmenge gleich bleibt. Als Gegenleitung für diesen Verzicht verlangt dieser Staat von Ersten aber Geld oder andere Gegenleistungen. Man kauft also einem anderen Staat das Recht ab, eine bestimmte Menge CO2 in die Luft zu blasen. Das ist der Handel mit Emissionen.

**B**
**eine aktive Klimaschutzpolitik im Stromsektor**
Eine Klimaschutzpolitik ist ein Bündel von geplanten und beschlossenen Maßnahmen, deren Ziel es ist, das Klima zu schützen. Aktiv ist eine solche Politik, wenn sie zukunftsorientiert ist, und gleichzeitig bedingt, dass Maßnahmen ergriffen werden, sie sonst nicht ergriffen worden wären (andernfalls wäre sie passiv, also abwartend).
Der Stromsektor ist jener Teil der Energiewirtschaft, der die Erzeugung und Verteilung elektrischer Energie betrifft.

**C**
**obsolet**
Etwas ist obsolet, wenn es veraltet, nicht mehr zeitgemäß oder überholt ist. Etwas das obsolet ist, wurde von etwas anderem, das besser ist, verdrängt.

---

Der Satz sagt also aus:

> Jenes Bündel geplanter Maßnahmen, welches sich mit dem Teil der Energiewirtschaft befasst, der die Erzeugung und Verteilung elektrischer Energie betrifft, wird nicht dadurch veraltet und überholt, dass man innerhalb Europas mit dem Recht, Treibhausgase auszustoßen, Handel treibt.

Comment: Adjektiv? Meintest du vielleicht Adverb?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Nein. Ein Adverb beschreibt die Eigenschaft eines Verbs (z.B. »Ilse spricht langsam«. »Langsam« ist hier eine Eigenschaft des Verbs »spricht«, nicht eine Eigenschaft von »Ilse«). Ein Adjektiv beschreibt die Eigenschaft eines Nomens oder auch einer Nominalphrase. Das Wort »obsolet« beschreibt eine Eigenschaft der zweiten Nominalphrase (»eine aktive Klimaschutzpolitik im Stromsektor«). Das Verb »macht« hat in diesem Satz keine besondere Eigenschaft, insbesondere ist es nicht obsolet.

Comment: Wer schon mit dem Originalsatz Schwierigkeiten hat, wird den letzten (sehr langen und verschachtelten) Satz deiner Antwort kaum nachvollziehen können.

Comment: Mir ist zwar nicht ganz klar, warum ich fünfeinhalb Jahre nach dem Verfassen dieser Antwort plötzlich mit einem 100-Punkte-Bounty belohnt wurde, aber ich möchte mich dem edlen und mir unbekannten Spender bedanken.